# How do the control points in CGContextAddCurveToPoint relate to the actual curve formula

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to implement `CGContextAddCurveToPoint()` in my app. In addition to the starting point and ending points, the function also takes two control points.

I need to know the exact formula of the curve so I can calculate the shortest distance from the curve to a tapped point, so I'm just wondering if anyone know how, mathematically, the two control points affect the cubic function which it is supposed to draw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position of a point relative to a Bezier curve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920687/position-of-a-point-relative-to-a-bezier-curve)

Answer (score 0):

That's a Bézier Curve. You'll find more info about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and there are plenty of resources on the Net about finding the "distance to a bezier curve", among which [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920687/position-of-a-point-relative-to-a-bezier-curve).

Comment: Thanks :) hate vector math and wikipedia's definition but I'll hack through it :P